# What are the complete list of benefits for the American Ambassador program?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

So way back when the 3ds first came out, I got the Ambassador program along with my purchase of the game because of the price drop. At first it was all well and good I saw a ton of free retro games because of it and I got a few specialty Miis through MiiPlaza that my brother didn't get but with the new 3ds out I was just wondering what all of the benefits were for the Ambassador program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Nintendo Wikia:

> The Nintendo 3DS Ambassador Program offers ten NES games for early
>   adopters and also offers ten Game Boy Advance games starting December
>   16, 2011, making twenty total. 
>   In addition to the twenty free games, Nintendo 3DS Ambassadors may
>   also download a special Ambassador Certificate. The certificate has a
>   notifications feature, which when toggled 'On' allows the player to
>   receive special notifications exclusive to Nintendo 3DS Ambassadors.

For the full list of 20 games, you can check [here](http://nintendo.wikia.com/wiki/Nintendo_3DS_Ambassador_Program)